# Query on Doctrine class table inheritance with required fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine, discriminator, class-table-inheritance

My domain has a parent `IncidenceMessage` class and several child classes (i.e. `IncidenceMessageText`).
I have the following **class table inheritance** configuration:

```
Domain\Model\IncidenceMessage\IncidenceMessage:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Infrastructure\Domain\Model\IncidenceMessage\DoctrineIncidenceMessageRepository
    table: incidence_messages
    inheritanceType: JOINED
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type
        type: string
        length: 30
    discriminatorMap:
        text: IncidenceMessageText
        image: IncidenceMessageImage
        audio: IncidenceMessageAudio
        video: IncidenceMessageVideo
    fields:
        ...
```

I can create any `IncidenceMessage` entity correctly.

Having only a `IncidenceMessageText` in database, when I try to fetch incidence messages I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Domain\Model\File\FileId::__construct() must be of the type string, null given
```

(`FileId` is a value object that represents the id of a File entity)

`IncidenceMessageImage` has a `File` field that is a foreign key and it is required.

It makes no sense to me that Doctrine fetches `File` when `IncidenceMessageText` doesn't have that field.

While debugging, I discovered that doctrine does a SELECT with LEFT JOINs with every single `IncidenceMessage` table and this calls my `FileTypeId::convertToPHPValue` method:

```
class FileIdType extends Type
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return new FileId($value);
    }
}
```

AFAIK, the problem here is that child classes have required fields but that shouldn't be a stopper, right?

Comment: Doctrine itself never uses the constructor of a class.  Everything is done using reflection to directly access class properties.  Your code is running new FileId() somewhere.

Comment: @Cerad Actually, new FileId() is on Custom DBAL Type (method convertToPHPValue) but I don't get why it is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible workaround. On my custom DBAL Type `FileIdType`, I checked if the value was null before instantiating `FileId`:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class FileIdType extends Type
{
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value ? new FileId($value) : null;
    }
}
```